# Infinite scrolling (TableView / CollectionView) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make an infinite scroll up and down both for tableView and collectionView in Swift.

The following works: tableView infinite scroll up and down; collectionView infinite scroll down.

So what does not work: collectionView infinite scroll up.

And I wonder what are the reasons for such a behaviour, since the code for `scrollViewDidScroll` method is the same both for tableView and collectionView.

Here is the full code (please note there are 2 classes - one for tableview and the other for collectionview):

```
import UIKit

let fireRequestDistance = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
let numberOfItemsPerRequest = 50

class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    var isLoadingNext: Bool = false
    var isLoadingPrev: Bool = false
    var items: [Int] = Array(0...100)
    @IBOutlet var scrollitem: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollitem.delegate = self
        scrollitem.dataSource = self
        scrollitem.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: items.count / 2, section: 0), at: .middle, animated: false)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        items.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(items[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        
        if !isLoadingNext, scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.bounds.height > scrollView.contentSize.height - fireRequestDistance {
            isLoadingNext = true
            print("Loading next")

            let max = self.items.last!
            let newItems = Array((max + 1)...(max + numberOfItemsPerRequest))
            let indexPaths = (self.items.count..<(self.items.count + numberOfItemsPerRequest)).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
            self.items += newItems
            self.scrollitem.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)
            self.isLoadingNext = false

        }
        
        if !isLoadingPrev, scrollView.contentOffset.y < scrollView.frame.height {
            isLoadingPrev = true

            let min = self.items.first!
            let newItems = Array((min - numberOfItemsPerRequest)..<min)
            let indexPaths = (0..<numberOfItemsPerRequest).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
            items = newItems + self.items
            scrollitem.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)
            print("fired")
            self.isLoadingPrev = false
            
        }
    }
}

class CollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    var isLoadingNext: Bool = false
    var isLoadingPrev: Bool = false
    var items: [Int] = Array(0...100)
    @IBOutlet var scrollitem: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        scrollitem.delegate = self
        scrollitem.dataSource = self
        scrollitem.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: items.count / 2, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)

    }
    
    func random() -> UIColor {
            return UIColor(red: .random(in: 0...1),
                           green: .random(in: 0...1),
                           blue: .random(in: 0...1),
                           alpha: 1.0)
        }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        items.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = random()
        return cell
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        
        if !isLoadingNext, scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.bounds.height > scrollView.contentSize.height - fireRequestDistance {
            isLoadingNext = true

            let max = self.items.last!
            let newItems = Array((max + 1)...(max + numberOfItemsPerRequest))
            let indexPaths = (self.items.count..<(self.items.count + numberOfItemsPerRequest)).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
            self.items += newItems
            self.scrollitem.insertItems(at: indexPaths)
            self.isLoadingNext = false

        }
        
        if !isLoadingPrev, scrollView.contentOffset.y < scrollView.frame.height {
            isLoadingPrev = true

            let min = self.items.first!
            let newItems = Array((min - numberOfItemsPerRequest)..<min)
            let indexPaths = (0..<numberOfItemsPerRequest).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
            items = newItems + self.items
            scrollitem.insertItems(at: indexPaths)
            print("fired")
            self.isLoadingPrev = false
            
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that  this part of code: `if !isLoadingPrev, scrollView.contentOffset.y < scrollView.frame.height` is called ONCE for tableView and many-many times for collectionView (up scrolling).

So for tableView it works as expected (new lines are smoothly added at the beginning of the tableview, once, and contentoffset is also smoothly continuing to change). In turn, for collectionview - hundrends of new items are randomly added to collectionview, everything is freezing, including the contentoffset.

Scrolling down works perfectly both for tableview and collection view.

Why is that? How can I fix it?

Thank you in advance! Kind regards

Comment: May be because in collection view the number of cell per line may be more than one. This may confuse the collection view scroll algorithm. You may need to insert as much cell as there is in a line.

Comment: Hi! Thank you. Tried this (as there are 6 items per row in my collection view, I've changed numberOfItemsPerRequest to 60. Does not work. The problem with the contentOffset - when scrolling up it is expected to bounce down smoothly, but it keeps climbing to zero, so newItems are added over and over